# How create a vertical label with correct width and height?

Tags: java, javafx, rotation, label

I need to visualize some data very compact. Due to limited hight of each data container, I decided to move the heading of each container to the side and rotate it vertically. When rotating the label, it sticks to its parent's dimensions. The maximum length of the label is therefore limited by the width of the parent. How can I accomplish that the label's maxWidth is the actual maxHeight of the parent pane?

For each container, I use a GridPane. The label is inside a StackPane to set a border or to change the background color.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test extends Application {

  public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        // Part of the code

        GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
        StackPane namePane;
        Label nameLabel;

        // ...

        // Header
        gridPane.getColumnConstraints().add(new ColumnConstraints(40.0));
        // Index
        gridPane.getColumnConstraints().add(new ColumnConstraints(50.0));
        // Name
        gridPane.getColumnConstraints().add(new ColumnConstraints(100.0,150.0,400));

        // int rows = ...; // Any integer between 1 and 6
        int rows = 5;

        for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            gridPane.getRowConstraints().add(new RowConstraints(30));
        }

        namePane = new StackPane();

        nameLabel = new Label("Name-123456789");
        nameLabel.setStyle("-fx-rotate: -90;");

        namePane.getChildren().add(nameLabel);
        gridPane.add(namePane,0,0,1,rows);

        // ...

        // Debug only
        gridPane.setGridLinesVisible(true);

        // just for running the example
        Scene scene = new  Scene(gridPane,700,700);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Below two images representing how I would expect the label to look and how it actually looks.

[image: How it should look]
[image: How it looks so far]

I've already tried to change the maxWidth of the Lable to Double.MAX_VALUE without success.

```
nameLabel.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
```

Comment: Create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Sedrick The code should work and represent the problem. Also, I just added an example row number.

Comment: the code doesn't even compile (it's not complete) how could it possibly work (in the sense of representing the problem). Please read the referenced help page and provide an example as suggested ..

Comment: @kleopatra Of course it does. I just commented out the ... in case you didn't notice that.

Comment: you really want _us_ to write the boiler-plate around the start method to make it runnable? *head-shaking ... it's _your_ problem, in case you didn't notice ;)

Comment: @kleopatra I just thought that it might be easier to understand when I just post the necessary code. I just posted a complete test class. Hope that works for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`StackPane` treats the `Label` as if the position was not modified by transforms. This also affects the computed sizes of the `StackPane`.

To fix this you could wrap the `Label` in a `Parent` that does consider transformations when calculating it's size: [`Group`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Group.html)

```
namePane.getChildren().add(new Group(nameLabel));
```

**Note:** This does not resize the `Label`, if the height of `namePane` becomes too small to contain it. To achieve that effect, you'd need to implement your own layout.